# Refactor SELECT WHERE AND OR EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE
    a.field = @fieldValue
    AND (YEAR(a.myDate) = @y
         OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM b
                    WHERE b.Id = a.Id)
         OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM c
                    WHERE c.Id = a.Id)
        )
```

How can this be rewritten in a simpler way ?

Comment: It can be written more aesthetically, but the logic seems sound.

Comment: What's the goal of refactoring here?  What are you trying to "fix"?

Comment: Personally, i would actually expand `YEAR(a.myDate)=@y` to make it SARGable. Also what does `...` represent? Is there more here?

Comment: my solution using LEFT JOIN is more compact, but less modular. If each OR EXIST is actually a complex subquery involving multiple joins, being modular is a great advantage.

Comment: I am merely trying to simplify a large SQL script

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I am still thinking about a cte based replacement. Does that make sense ? Is EXISTS considered legacy SQL, where cte could be considered a more modern approach ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . CTEs are not necessary -- the subqueries are referred to only once.  `EXISTS` is a central part of SQL and in no way "legacy".  Your code is fine and possibly the most efficient way to implement the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I can't see anything wrong with the query you have, `EXISTS` seems to be the best choice here, as a `JOIN` could create duplicate rows (as I display in the comment under one of your answers). As I mentioned in the comment, I would actually expand the query to use a SARGable `WHERE` clause on the date column:

```
DECLARE @fieldValue varchar(10) = 'SomeValue',
        @y int = 2019;

DECLARE @StartDate date = CONCAT(@y,'0101'),
        @EndDate date = CONCAT(@y+1,'0101');

SELECT a.* --This should be expanded if using a persisted object
FROM a
WHERE a.field = @fieldValue
  AND (a.myDate >= @StartDate AND a.MyDate < @EndDate
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.Id = a.Id)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM c WHERE c.Id = a.Id));
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution using cte:

```
WITH bb AS (
    SELECT b.Id
    FROM b
    JOIN a ON b.Id=a.Id
    GROUP BY b.Id
),
WITH cc AS (
    SELECT c.Id
    FROM c
    JOIN a ON c.Id=a.Id
    GROUP BY c.Id
)
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN bb ON a.Id=bb.Id
LEFT JOIN cc ON a.Id=cc.Id
WHERE
a.field=@fieldValue AND (YEAR(a.myDate)=@y OR bb.Id IS NOT NULL OR cc.Id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: GROUP BY not needed if using PK

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.Id=b.Id
LEFT JOIN c ON a.Id=c.Id
WHERE a.field=@fieldValue AND (YEAR(a.myDate)=@y OR b.Id IS NOT NULL OR c.Id IS NOT NULL)
```

is equivalent and more readable (simpler)

Comment: What if `a` and `b` or `a` and `c` have a one to many relationship? This wouldn't bring the same result set back if that type of relationship exists.

Comment: What happened to `YEAR(a.myDate)=@y` and `...` as well?

Comment: WHERE a.field=@fieldValue AND (YEAR(a.myDate)=@y OR b.Id IS NOT NULL OR c.Id IS NOT NULL)

Comment: These queries are very different to each other. in this [very simple example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91976cc6b9aef3c5079aab464eb399e3) the first query (in your question) returns 1 row with 3 columns, however, in the 2nd (from your answer), there are 7 columns and 4 rows. The result sets are completely different.